# matrix with two lengths, eliminating a row by passing [-1,] via paste to model matrix

Tags: r

I have the following expression where I paste via as.formula the function expression (form by the two expressions using paste). A is an object dataframe

```
pastevar <- paste(c("z2 ~ ", paste(A, collapse=" + ")))
X <- model.matrix(as.formula(pastevar)) [,-1]
```

length of z2 is one row shorter (200 elements) than length of A (199 elements). A is passed to the second expression with the paste expression above as

```
> A
[1] "Dxi2" "Dxu2" "Dxa2" "Dxb2" "Dxc2" "Dxd2"
```

Is there a way to pass an instruction like A[-1,] to eliminate the first row from A by passing it either in the pastevar expression or in the model matrix so X model.matrix matches in length.

When I use the below expression I get incorrect number of dimensions

```
pastevar <- paste(c("z2 ~ ", paste(A[-1,], collapse=" + ")))
Error en A[-1, ] : número incorreto de dimensiones
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R can't parse a negative index, instead tell it to start from the second row and go to the last row:

```
pastevar <- paste(c("z2 ~ ", paste(A[2:nrow(A),], collapse=" + ")))
```

EDIT:
In response to your edit adding the data itself, according to the dimensions of A:

```
pastevar <- paste(c("z2 ~ ", paste(A[2:length(A)], collapse=" + ")))
```

And if you want to cut off x columns at the end:

```
A[1:(length(A)-x)]
```

Comment: `pastevar <- paste(c("z2 ~ ", paste(A[2:(nrow(A)-x),], collapse=" + ")))` where x is however many rows you wish to eliminate at the end

Comment: Thank you. One question for eliminating the last row/s what would be then the expression if I do not know the final row number. If I can not parse negative numbers is the only solution to know the ending row number.

Comment: pastevar <- paste(c("z2 ~", paste(A[1:(nrow(A)-1)], collapse=" + ")))   Error en 1:(nrow(A) - 1) : argument of length 0 . Does this happen because A is not an object? A corresponds to the names of the variables, that are later pick up by the expression as.formula(pastevar)

Comment: It doesn't matter what is in A, it's the dimensions of A that matter. Also, you're missing comma: A[1:(nrow(A)-1),]

Comment: I have edited the question including A [1] "Dxi2" "Dxu2" "Dxa2" "Dxb2" "Dxc2" "Dxd2"  as A has no dimensions as it is passed to the expression. However later in the expression as.formula(pastevar) it has dimensions

Comment: I have edited my response. A is not dimensionless, but is a vector of 6 strings.